# If statement not working in string search

Tags: java, string, if-statement, data-structures

**The task**

The function named getKey1() is supposed to return the substring which occurs the maximum number of times in a string.

**What have I done?**

```
public class Proc {
public static String getKey1(String str)
{
    LinkedList link = new LinkedList();
    int i = 0;
    int t = 0;
    String pattern = "";
    l1:
    while(i < str.length())
    {
        if(str.charAt(i) != ' ')
        {
            t = i;
            for(t = i; t < str.length(); t++)
            {
                if(str.charAt(t) == ' ')
                    break;
                else if( t >= str.length())
                    break l1;
            }
            pattern = str.substring(i, t);
            link.add(pattern);
            i += pattern.length();
        }
        else
            i++;
    }


    LinkedList link2 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList link3 = new LinkedList();
    Iterator f = link.iterator();

    while(f.hasNext())
    {
        Object o = f.next();
        String ss = (String)o;
        if(link3.contains(o))
        {
            Iterator m = link2.iterator();
            while(m.hasNext())
            {
                Object ro = m.next();
                struct sto = (struct)ro;
                String so = sto.str;
                if(so.equals(ss))
                {
                    sto.count++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            link3.add(ss);
            link2.add(new struct(ss, 1));
        }
    }

        Iterator k = link2.iterator();
        struct min = new struct("a", 10);

        while(k.hasNext())
        {
            Object ost = k.next();
            struct spt = (struct)ost;
            System.out.println(spt.str + "  " + spt.count);
            if(spt.count > min.count);
            {
                min.str = spt.str;
                min.count = spt.count;
            }
        }
    return min.str;
    }
}
```

The struct class:

```
public class struct {
public int count;
public String str;
public struct(String str, int count)
{
    this.str = str;
    this.count = count;
}

}
```

The main class:

```
public class Asdf {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Proc.getKey1("This is a string. boom boom kaboom boom"));
}

}
```

The output is

```
This  1

is  1

a  1

string  1

boom  3

kaboom  1


kaboom
```

**The problem**

This is actually a test run which shows how many times the substring occurs in the string str. So according to this output, "boom" should be returned to main, but "kaboom" is returned. With further testing, I came to the conclusion that there is a problem in the last if statement:
    if(spt.count > min.count)
It looks as if the program always goes inside this if statement no matter what. I changed it to
    if(4 < 3)
and still got the same output.

Comment: `break l1;` Uugh. Such a horrible programming style. I'm not surprised there are problems.

Comment: Why you don't use HashMap?

Comment: There's a semi-colon on the end of the if statement in question in effect marking the end of the if, hence why the following block is always executed.

Comment: yeah. what a mistake! thanks :|
+1

Comment: There should also be struct min = new struct("", 0) instead of struct min = new struct("", 10) otherwise the output would be a if the maximum frequency of a substring is less than or equal to 10!

Answer (score 2):

All `if(spt.count > min.count);` does is to execute the null statement `;` if it evaluates to true. The bit in braces after this line is always executed.

I'm sure that control flow is not intended.

Also, consider refactoring away from your `break label;` anti-pattern. It makes code brittle: too easy to accidentally move a label forgetting someone has a `break` dependent on its precise location.

Comment: yeah. I was actually trying to solve this with lots of different logics and ended on one. But yes, sorry for the bad code. +1

Answer (score 1):

You have a ";" on the end of your IF line.

```
if(spt.count > min.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Memran has answered your specific question - the block below the "if" is getting run unconditionally because the semicolon ends the if and the block is then just a block.

However, unless I've misunderstood what you're trying to do here, that's frankly the least of your problems :-)

It looks like when you say "substring", you really mean "space-separated token". Assuming that's the case, here's a nice straightforward way of splitting out the words, counting them, then looking for the largest count:

```
String input = "foo bar baz quux quux bar baz foo bar wibble";
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));

Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String word : words) 
{
    Integer count = counts.get(word);
    count = (count == null? 1 : count+1);
    counts.put(word, count);
}

int max = 0;
String maxWord = null;
for (String word : counts.keySet()) 
{
    Integer count = counts.get(word);
    if(count > max) 
    {
        max = count;
        maxWord = word;
    }
}

System.out.println("Most-used word is "+maxWord+" with "+max+" uses.");
```

I'm sure there are also smarter ways to do this if performance mattered. But often simple and straightforward is better.